# Setting up C code highlighting

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, filetype-c

I've used vim for mostly python or web-related projects. Now I'm trying to see if I can use it to write some C code. The first thing that I've noticed is whatever setup I have, doesn't have any C code highlighting, for example:

[image]

Is there some plugin I need to grab, or what's the simplest way to get code highlighting on the C language?

Comment: check `:verbose set filetype?`—vim's builtin-support for C is world-class, so I'm shocked you don't see anything

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, it seems that this is more related to my `colors/TextMate.vim` rules than to the syntax rules itself. It seems some colorschemes work OK with C and others either partially work or don't work at all, so have some digging to do...